# Power Query - Find if one condition is true and the other is false

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I don't know how to ask the question. I need to find out how may Households have at least one participant that works Part-Time but no one in the household works Full-Time.

The green ones show which ones should be counted and the red shouldn't be. THe red shows that two participants in household 14, one is working part-time, the other full-time, so they shouldn't be counted.

THis is a question i need to find the answer for at work and I don't want to keep manually counting through a spreadsheet to find part-time but no full-time participants in a household.

[image]

Ive only tried using filters in Power BI because I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"HHID"}, {{"Count", each if  Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Part-Time")) >= 1 and Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Full-Time")) = 0  then 1 else 0, type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

note your example seems wrong for HHID 13

[image]

or to total the Count column as an additional step:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"HHID"}, {{"Count", each if  Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Part-Time")) >= 1 and Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Full-Time")) = 0  then 1 else 0, type number}}),
MasterCount=List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[Count])
in MasterCount
```

[image]

EDIT

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"HHID"}, {
    {"1PT", each if  Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Part-Time")) >= 1 and Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Full-Time")) = 0  then 1 else 0, type number},
    {"Unemp", each if Table.RowCount(_) = Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Unemployed")) then 1 else 0, type number},
    {"1FT", each if Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Employment Status] = "Full-Time")) >0 then 1 else 0, type number}
}),
Totals= #table({"1PT", "Unemp","1FT"},{{List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[1PT]),List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[Unemp]),List.Sum(#"Grouped Rows"[1FT])}})
in  Totals
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which step in applied steps would I put that? I've tried different ones to no avail. I see it looks like it works, thank you! Apologies for not knowing where it goes.

Comment: you need to go into home...advanced editor...  remove your in XXXX line, and the add two lines from above starting with #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source...   replacing the word Source with the name of whatever your prior step is

Comment: You are correct 13 is wrong. Thank you that did work. Anyway you would be willing to help me answer these two additonal questions that go along with that. I was hoping i could figure it out on my own.

how many HHIDs where all participants are unemployed and

how many HHIDs where at least one participant is employed full-time.

Thank you regarless if you answer my additional questions.

Comment: See edit above.  you should be able to get on from there

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much! I really need to take some classes to learn this. So much you can do!